# How to play a video automatically from local directory

Tags: html, iframe, video

I am trying to play a Video from my System's Local directory automatically but i am not able to do it instead getting error as ..

```
The address wasn't understood
```

The video is available in my local directory still not able to play it .

Here is my Markup ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="D:\Downloaded\video.MP4">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to play it automatically..Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't support Windows paths with backslashes. You need to convert them to URL syntax.

A simple way to do this is to paste the path into the address line of a browser. Most browsers will then convert the Windows path to a valid URL.

Otherwise, the correct URL should be like `file:/D:/Downloaded/video.MP4`

Comment: Ok.Now my video is running but it is displaying in middle of the web page with around `150px` away from left and right.How to display it in full screen with `500px` height?

Comment: Please post a new question for this.

Comment: Am sorry to tell you but SO will say me to wait for `90` minutes before posting new..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `file:///` prefix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="file:///D:/Downloaded/video.MP4">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok.Now my video is running but it is displaying in middle of the web page with around 150px away from left and right.How to display it in full screen with 500px height?